# How to reproduce draggable windows

Tags: qt, qt5

So i am working on an editor for a game engine. Everything works just fine with a single problem. The UI is not customizable. How can this be reproduced?

Comment: What do you mean with "reproduce draggable windows", and what you need to customize? Can you at least provide an example of what you already have and what you are trying to get?

Comment: @musicamante I mean you know those windows where tou have like your filesystem and the code editor and you can drag em around? Thats what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Looks like you're maybe looking for https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html?

Comment: @SirDarius yup thx didn't know it existed

Answer (score 0):

SirDarius told me that QDockWidget might be what I needed and is true, thats exactly what I needed.